# Parallel tests in Django: ERROR 1062 (23000)

Tags: python, mysql, django, unit-testing

I have weird behavior of Django tests in parallel mode:
Command to run tests: `python manage.py test --parallel`

Sometimes it works fine but in random moments I got error during cloning DB.

```
Cloning test database for alias 'default'...
ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 237: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'auth_permission.PRIMARY'
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
```

I did it on empty DB (ran `python manage.py drop_test_database` before running tests)

Migrations applied successfully. And after that I got error with cloning, and tests that ran on `failed` copies raised the next error `MySQLdb.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_dbname_8.django_content_type' doesn't exist")`

This is very strange because sometimes I have successful test runs. Maybe the reason is MySQL, which does not support parallel execution well?

P.S. without `--parallel` flag tests work fine

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue but no solution as yet. This issue started occurring on upgrading from MySQL 5.7 to 8.0 in order to upgrade from Django 4.1 to Django 4.2. It seems as if MySQL 8.0 is more strict on duplication but no real evidence to back this up as yet.

Comment: Just out of interest, do you happen to use DjangoRestFramework?

Comment: @NMunro this issue from Django project, not DRF

Comment: @Sergey I went down a wrong line of thought, and thought DRF was involved as we have the same problem and mistakenly thought our DRF permissions were involved, they obviously weren't. We're still studying the problem ourselves, but haven't found anything concrete yet :/

Comment: @NMunro Now I'm using `pytest` to start tests (but code wasn't changed, it's still class-bases unit tests), and the problem was solved -_-

Comment: @Sergey Is pytest running these tests in parallel though?

Comment: @NMunro Yes, using https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/