# Django test parallel fails while clone database

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-testing

I have weird behavior of Django tests in parallel mode: Command to run tests: python manage.py test --parallel

Sometimes it works fine but in random moments I got error during cloning DB.

Cloning test database for alias 'default'...
`ERROR 1062 (23000) at line 237: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'auth_permission.PRIMARY'`
mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
I did it on empty DB (ran python manage.py drop_test_database before running tests)

Migrations applied successfully. And after that I got error with cloning, and tests that ran on failed copies raised the next error `MySQLdb.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_dbname_8.django_content_type' doesn't exist")`

This is very strange because sometimes I have successful test runs. Maybe the reason is MySQL, which does not support parallel execution well?

without --parallel flag tests work fine

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76713232/parallel-tests-in-django-error-1062-23000?noredirect=1#comment136057685_76713232